# How can I let `cloud function` find the source code uploaded from terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a nodejs app and use terraform to upload it to `Cloud function` in GCP. But I got below error from terraform command.

`Error: Error waiting for Creating CloudFunctions Function: Error code 3, message: Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.`

my terraform code is:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name = "${local.app_name}-function-${var.project_id}-${var.gcp_region}"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "archive" {
  name   = "${var.stage}-${local.app_name}-function.zip"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source = "../apps/dist/src.zip"
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "identity" {
  name        = "gcp-identity"
  description = "GCP Identity"
  runtime     = "nodejs14"

  available_memory_mb   = 512
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name
  trigger_http          = true
  entry_point           = "gcp-identity"
}
```

The src.zip file has only one file in the root `index.js`. The content of this file is:

```
"use strict";
exports.helloHttp = (req, res) => {
    res.send(`Hello ${JSON.stringify(req)}`);
};
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

I wonder why gcp can't find the function code? Is there a way for me to specify the source code path inside the zip file?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the `entry_point` should be the `exported function name` from `index.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because of your `.ts` file.

CloudFunction does not support typescript out of the box

You will need to transpile your code into .js before deploying it into CloudFunction.

Comment: I removed the .ts file from zip and it is now only one index.js file. But it still gives me this error. I have updated my question.